# Check if there is a dictionary with specific value in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to populate a Python data structure, whether list or dictionary or similar, with multiple values per entry, but I need to skip the entry if some value repeats.

For example lets say I have three lines of text with three values in each line, and two lines have the same first value:

```
AAA XXX 132
AAA YYY 465
BBB ZZZ 798
```

Result I want to get is an array or dictionary of two entries each all three values so that I could later iterate through it and get every value I can need.

For the moment I have an example like this:

```
teststring = 'AAA XXX 132\nAAA YYY 465\nBBB ZZZ 798'
a = []

count = 0
for line in teststring.splitlines():
    val1 = line[0:3]
    val2 = line[4:7]
    val3 = line[8:11]
    count = count + 1
    d = {'val1':val1, 'val2':val2, 'val3':val3}
    a.append(d)

for i in a:
    print i['val1'] + ' ' + i['val2'] + ' ' + i['val3']
```

(print is just an example, variable "a" will be passed to another function ant manipulated there further, so I would highly appreciate if values in dictionary would have meaningful "names", like `i['some_value']` instead of `i[1]`)

but instead of just `a.append(d)` I need to skip the second `AAA` line, something like

```
if d.['val1'] not in a:
    a.append(d)
```

I am pretty sure the solution if simple I just cant find it, please help.

---

This is how I did it after examining [flyingmeatball](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36179317/3441589)'s sugestion:

```
teststring = 'AAA XXX 132\nAAA YYY 465\nBBB ZZZ 798'
a = {}

for line in teststring.splitlines():
    val1 = line[0:3]
    val2 = line[4:7]
    val3 = line[8:11]
    if val1 not in a.keys():
        d = {'val1':val1, 'val2':val2, 'val3':val3}
        a[val1] = d

for i in a.values():
    print i['val1'] + ' ' + i['val2'] + ' ' + i['val3']
```

and if needed I can sort it like that:

```
aa = a.values()
aa.sort(key = lambda dict: dict['val1'])
for i in aa:
    print i['val1'] + ' ' + i['val2'] + ' ' + i['val3']
```

However I am not sure if this is the most optimal solution...

Comment: I don't really follow, what's your expected output?

Comment: why arent you doing what you wrote ? if d.['val1'] not in a.values():
    a.append(d)

Comment: a is a list, so you can't call values, you'll need something like `if d['val1'] not in a:`

Comment: ya, right, i dont know why i thought it was a dict

Comment: I need a data structure to be passed to another function, I do not need it to output something, and I need for values to have some kind of names, that's why I would like to use dictionary for storing values (sorry if I say something stupid, I'm very new to Python...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is just a dict, where you only read it into the dict if it doesn't exist yet?

```
teststring = 'AAA XXX 132\nAAA YYY 465\nBBB ZZZ 798'

outputDict = {}

for line in teststring.splitlines():
    val1 = line[0:3]
    val2 = line[4:7]
    val3 = line[8:11]

    if val1 not in outputDict:
        outputDict[val1] = [val2,val3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary comprehension from Python 2.7 onwards. I am using `reversed` to ensure you keep the first entry in your data, rather than the last

```
data ={x.split()[0]:x.split() for x in reversed(teststring.split('\n'))}
for value in data.values();
    print value[0] + ' ' + value[1] + ' ' + value[2]
```

This outputs:

```
AAA XXX 132
BBB ZZZ 798
```

Explaining the dictionary comprehension in further detail, the following bit of logic splits your input string by carriage return and reverses the list (I will come back to this later):

```
reversed(teststring.split('\n'))
```

The next bit of logic creates a dictionary entry after splitting the value by space using the first value of the resulting array as the dictionary key:

```
x.split()[0]:x.split()
```

The dictionary value will be overwritten if there is an element with the same key and therefore the inputs needs to be processed in reverse order by using `reversed`

Comment: cool, going in reverse to overwrite the key with the first value

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this depending on your goal is to handle the values in a separate container to check if already inserted.

```
teststring = 'AAA XXX 132\nAAA YYY 465\nBBB ZZZ 798'

a = []
val1_set = set()

count = 0
for line in teststring.splitlines():
    val1 = line[0:3]
    val2 = line[4:7]
    val3 = line[8:11]
    count = count + 1
    d = {'val1':val1, 'val2':val2, 'val3':val3}

    if val1 not in val1_set:
       a.append(d)

    val1_set.add(val1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am slightly confused about what you are trying to achieve, but this is my attempt:

```
teststring = 'AAA XXX 132\nAAA YYY 465\nBBB ZZZ 798'

a = []

count = 0
for line in teststring.splitlines():
    val1 = line[0:3]
    val2 = line[4:7]
    val3 = line[8:11]
    count = count + 1
    d = {'val1':val1, 'val2':val2, 'val3':val3}
    found = False
    for i in a:
        if i['val1'] == d['val1']:
            found = True
    if not found:
        a.append(d)

for i in a:
    print(i['val1'] + ' ' + i['val2'] + ' ' + i['val3'])
```

This produces:

```
AAA XXX 132
BBB ZZZ 798
```

If you want it to check if 'val1' exists as any of the possible 3 values, so you start counting AAA BBB XXX and BBB CCC YYY as duplicates (BBB appears twice), then you can modify it as follows:

```
if i['val1'] == d['val1'] or i['val2'] == d['val1'] or i['val3'] == d['val1']:
```